# MustacheJS no-conflict

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, mustache

I'm working on a chrome extension, the extension relies on MustacheJS for templating.

When running my extension while visiting wallmart.com I get the following error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: Mustache is not defined`

My guess is that wallmart is also using Mustache but I couldn't find any proof that, maybe they are not?

Anyways - to the question:
Is it possible to run Mustache under a different name?
For example instead of calling `Mustache.Render(...)`, calling `myVar.Render(...)`

Couldn't find anything in the documentation..

**Please note:**

- I'm any not using AMD/Require of some sort
- When running my extension on other websites everything work just fine..

Comment: Content scripts run in their own sandbox, separate from the page so I think unless you inject a page script using `<script>` element "hack", you don't need to worry about conflicts with page scripts. There's probably something else going on. Try to [debug](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging) your script and mustasheJS.

Comment: @wOxxOm - I'm injecting this using the dirty hack :{ any ideas?

Comment: 1. Maybe it's possible to use the standard content script technique instead of the hack so the question needs the relevant part of code you use. 2. Another idea is to locally modify the mustache.js script file and rename its global object to something unique like `__orz_Mustache` or even do it dynamicaly: read the script code with XHR/AJAX, replace all `/\bMustache\b/g` with `"Mustache" + btoa(Math.random())`, inject the script code, and then use this identifier instead of `Mustache`.